# Chromium not available from repository on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, browser

I am running Debian Jessie on a Cubox (I am not very familiar with Debian yet). And according to [the debian page](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/chromium) the package should be available in the repos. Unfortunatly I cannot find it or it is not available for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get install chromium
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package chromium is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
chromium-inspector chromium-bsu

E: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
$ cat sources.list
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you scroll down to the bottom of the [Chromium package page](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/chromium), you'll see that the package is only available on `amd64` and `i386`. Your Cubox runs `armhf`, so the package isn't available for your system...

It has [built on `armhf`](https://buildd.debian.org/status/logs.php?pkg=chromium-browser&arch=armhf) in the past, but the latest attempts (in 2013) failed because of compiler errors. You could always try rebuilding it yourself, but it will probably take quite a long time!

Comment: Would I not be able to use for example ubuntus package? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/armhf/chromium-browser. Oh well, the package search for armhf on ubuntu the browser isn't available on armhf. But there must be a way. Because I already saw it running on a Cubox.

Comment: You could try [the Vivid version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/armhf/chromium-browser/41.0.2272.76-0ubuntu1.1134) and its dependencies, which is available on `armhf`.

Comment: It didn't work with the Vivid version but the latest (14.04) did. Thank you.